# Convert IPMask to IPAddr

Tags: go

I want to display an object of type `net.IPMask` in the same notation as `net.IPAddr`. I want to be able to do this for both IPv4 and IPv6 masks. For instance:

"fffffe00" ---> "255.255.254.0"

I could accomplish this by manually parsing the object of type `net.IPMask`. However, is there a way to accomplish this by converting an object of type `net.IPMask` to an object of type `net.IPAddr`, ideally using functions built in to the net package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`net.IPMask`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPMask) is just an IP address, so you can convert it to a [`net.IP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP) and call its [`String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP.String) method to get a formatted IP address:

```
mask := net.CIDRMask(23, 32)
addr := net.IP(mask).String()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/A_oJfD8lpwP

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!